# Composer keeps running on php 5.4

Tags: php, composer-php

I added **PHP 5.5** path to my `$PATH` in `.bashrc` and it runs perfectly when I run `$ php -v`.

However, when I run `composer install` (composer is installed in `/usr/bin`) **inside my project root** (the folder with the `composer.json` file) it tries to run using **PHP 5.4**.

PHP 5.4 is on `/usr/bin` and 5.5 is on `/usr/local/php-5.5.36-cgi/bin`.

Why is it running with 5.4 and how do I make it use 5.5?

Comment: the first thing to come to mind is have you run `source ~/.bashrc` to reload the ENV vars? Second would be check if /home/.composer/ contains any configuration that is specifying the php binary to use.

Comment: Yes, I did run `source`, and there is only a `.htaccess` file inside `.composer`.  It's weird cause it only runs on PHP 5.4 inside of my project root. Outside of it, composer will use 5.5 (or at least it wont warn me about using 5.4)

Comment: if you do phpinfo() in your project root, what php version is displayed?

Comment: if you run composer without PHP before it, it runs /usr/bin/php in its bash script.. 
Try: php composer install

Comment: @Pheagey `phpinfo()` on web says 5.5

Comment: @Svetlio exatcly, how do I modify that so that I don't have to do `$ php /usr/lib64/plesk/composer.phar install`  but just `composer install`

Comment: The right way is to alias the 5.5 as /usr/bin/php and you can keep the 4 as /usr/local/php-5.4.xx/bin

Comment: Are you using phpenv?

Comment: @Svetlio you mean `alias '/user/bin/php'=path/to/my/php5.5` ?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco If you don't need 5.4, I'd upgrade system wide to 5.5. Under the assumption that is not possible in your .bashrc add the alias
alias `php='path/to/my/php5.5'` should do the trick for your users account on the machine